# Flask / Python: Modify uploaded file data before saving

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I would like to be able to upload a csv file, then have a script in python do some modifications to the file, and finally save the file after changes to a specific folder. I have something like this, but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/tkp/Desktop/uploads_files'
app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] = ['.csv']
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/')
def index():
    files = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'])
    return render_template('index.html', files=files)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_files():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    
    filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
    
    if filename != '':
        
        uploaded_file.stream.seek(0)
        f = uploaded_file.read()
        
            #some change in the file
        
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
        
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/Users/tkp/Desktop/uploads_files/<filename>')
def upload(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename)
```

And HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Convert"></p>
    </form>
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to perform such an operation on the fly or do you have to save the uploaded file first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly, except the `f.save(...)` definition.

When you do `f = uploaded_file.read()`, the `f` is the result of the `.read()` operation, which is bytes, not a file.
You have to open another file and save the contents to it.
Don't forget to `.decode()` the bytes, to make it a string.

Here's a working snippet:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_files():

    uploaded_file = request.files['file']

    filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)

    if filename != '':

        uploaded_file.stream.seek(0)
        f = uploaded_file.read().decode()

        # WE don't want any failures
        f = f.replace("FAIL", "SUCCESS")

        filename_to_save = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename)
        with open(filename_to_save, "w") as file_to_save:
            file_to_save.write(f)

    return {"status": "OK"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could probably be a typo in your action attribute. Change this line:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```